# Update custom field of registration form on edit detail page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I create a registration form on registration page by using  shortcode  [woocommerce_simple_registration] and also add two custom fields (confirm password and phone) by following belo9w link:

https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203182373-How-to-add-custom-fields-in-user-registration-on-the-My-Account-page

so please let me know How to update these fields on edit page????

Comment: Normally in "My Account" page (when customer is logged in), the password is under "edit your password and account details" link and for phone is under "shipping and billing addresses" link… or not?

Comment: Yes, its coming under Billing Address case. If i edit Billing Address its showing me Phone field. Can i some how show this Phone field in acount details page?